# Creating an android Application containing only static data

Tags: android, sqlite, static-data

I am going to work on an android application.
The basic flow should be like :

**1. Main Activity**

---

```
**-cat1**
  -subcategory 1
  -subcategory 2
**-cat2**
  -subcategory 1
  -subcategory 2
**-cat3**
  -subcategory 1
  -subcategory 2
```

this should be the flow of application. Every Page contains static data only.
If we consider subcategory under category, it may contain some images and some data.

All Pages would be of same scene.

So, I just want to know what would be the best way to do so??

Can I just have to use resources only or database would come into picture?
Thanks.

Let Me add that I am clear with the flow my confusion resides into data storing only that what should be the best way to display static data only.

Editing again and again because I am not satisfied.
For data taking scrollable textview would be convenient?? I will put whole data in String.xml

Answer (score 0):

Different Tabs for Categories and activity for your subcategory page would be better in my opinion. You need not use any database since most of the data is static.

Comment: So for long paragraphs. I should write within strings?? or any other way is there..like webview.

Comment: WebView will be better for you as designing it much easier than a plain activity. This might help you: http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/creating-android-applications-with-html-user-interface/

Comment: Storing within local database (SQLite) worth??

Comment: It depends upon what are you trying to show. If you are trying to show a lot of data that sorts logically then only DB is required. As per your requirement I don't think you need DB but its all on your requirement.